# Add Django Rest Framework route to third party urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am using [Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) along with [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). This is my `urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()

djoser_urls = [
    path("auth/", include("djoser.urls")),
    path("auth/", include("djoser.urls.authtoken")),
]

urlpatterns = router.urls + djoser_urls
```

When using the browsable API at `localhost:8000/auth/` the `djoser` urls are available. So that is all working correctly.

What I need is to be able to browse to `localhost:8000/` and have the above route displayed as an option to click on. Currently there are no routes displayed in the browsable API at `localhost:8000/` even though if I manually type `localhost:8000/auth/` into the url then I am taken to the `djoser` urls.

In other words, when opening the browsable API at `localhost:8000/`, I would like the following to be available to click on:

```json
{
    "auth": "http://localhost:8000/auth/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in djozer, but this is a simple method:

In views.py:

```
def indexJson(request):
   data  = '{ \"auth\": \"http://localhost:8000/auth/\" }'
   return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

urls.py

```
path( route='', view=views.indexJson, name='index')
```